# How to get a Result from Image Capture and save it to Shared Preferences in Android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am building an app in which I want when the user clicks the imageview, the device camera app to launch and take a picture and set it to the imageview. I have accomplished that!!! But when I exit the app and re-open it the image has been deleted. How can I do it so the image is permanent?

My code:

```
private SessionManager session;
private static final int REQ_CODE = 1152;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
private Uri file;
private String fileName = "ImageTaken";
private ImageView imagePhoto;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_data);
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        session.checkLogin();
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        Toolbar tb = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.topBar);
        setSupportActionBar(tb);
        String name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);
        TextView watersName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.waitersName);
        TextView date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
        watersName.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + name + "</b>"));
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd" + "/" + "mm" + "/" + "yyyy");
        String text = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
        date.setText(text);
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String timeF = timeFormat.format(c.getTime());
        time.setText(timeF);
        Button btnnewworder = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnnewworder);
        btnnewworder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserData.this, Tables.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
            }
        });
        Button payment = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpayment);
        payment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogMessageDisplay.displayInfoMessage(UserData.this, "Payment Details", "There was no order made. \n Make an order and then tap the payment button.", AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);

            }
        });
        imagePhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.waiterPhoto);
        imagePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                file = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //file = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
            }
        });
    }
```

OnActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQ_CODE){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){


                imagePhoto.setImageURI(file);
                editor.putString(fileName, file.toString());
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(UserData.this, "Your file has been saved at " + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(UserData.this, "Action Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1) Initialize these:

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

2) Modify your `onCreate()` like:

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
imagePhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.waiterPhoto);
String commited = sharedPreferences.getString(fileName, null);
if(commited != null) {
    imagePhoto.setImageURI(Uri.parse(commited));
}
```

3) Modify your `onActivityResult()` like:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQ_CODE){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                imagePhoto.setImageURI(file);
                editor.putString(fileName, file.toString());
                editor.commit();
            }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(UserData.this, "Action Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

And then you will have your desired effect. Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 2):

`SharedPreferences` are not meant for holding quantities of data such as imagery.  They are meant for holding information about where an image is, or other small selections that the user has chosen.

If you want to save an image off, then you should do just that.  Save the image within a local file within the application and then retrieve it later.  You can save the location of that file in a `SharedPreference` object if you would like for you when you return.  If it is only one, then you can replace it with the next one in the same file name the next time a picture is taken.  This way you always have the latest image available since the last time that picture is taken; even after you shut down and restart the phone.